# How to free 2d array in C?

Tags: c, memory-management

I have the following code:

```
int **ptr = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int*)*N); 
for(int i=0;i<N;i++) 
     ptr[i]=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*N));
```

How can I free `ptr` using `free`? Should I loop over `ptr` and free `ptr[i]` or should I just do

```
free(ptr)
```

and `ptr` will be freed?

Comment: This is not about free, but I wanted to talk about malloc. As Srikanth has pointed out, it's good if you check the malloc failure. Please refer to this material: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451220/how-can-i-correctly-handle-malloc-failure-in-c-especially-when-there-is-more-th

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You will have to loop over `ptr[i]`, freeing each `int*` that you traverse, as you first suggest. For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    int* currentIntPtr = ptr[i];
    free(currentIntPtr);
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's wrong with just going through the loop with `free(ptr[i])`?

Comment: Nothing, I may be trying a bit too hard to make my code readable here!

Comment: Hi James, I tried doing it the way you've written and my program breaks.

_crtheap 0x0083000 void *
pUserData 0x0083c408 const void *

Why do you think this happens?

Basically it's a heap block modified past requested size, something like that!

Comment: @JamesBedford - Sorry I couldn't tag you on the previous one.

Comment: @RakshitKothari - I'm guessing it's the free where it's crashing? The most obvious answer would be that your value for N is greater than the size of your array referenced to by `ptr`.

Comment: @JamesBedford Why did you not just use free(ptr[i]) inside the loop ?

Comment: Just to more clearly lay out what's happening.
It might also make it easier to set a breakpoint and see the value of pointer thats about to be freed, if that's of interest to the developer.

Answer (score 29):

Just the opposite of allocation:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    free(ptr[i]);
free(ptr);
```

Comment: Will it give segmentation fault if I try to access a location that has been freed by me ?

Comment: @VaradBhatnagar: It's actually undefined behaviour. Could be segmentation fault - who knows!

Comment: I don't think you need the third line here.

Comment: @MohamedIbrahim: No, it's needed because the ptr was malloced: `int **ptr = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int*)*N);`

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you must loop over `ptr` and free each `ptr[i]`. To avoid memory leaks, the general rule is this: for each `malloc()`, there must be exactly one corresponding `free()`.

Answer (score 8):

### Simple

```
while (N) free(ptr[--N]);
free(ptr);
```

### Handsome

```
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1
typedef int BOOL;

void freev(void **ptr, int len, BOOL free_seg) {
    if (len < 0) while (*ptr) {free(*ptr); *ptr++ = NULL;}
    else while (len) {free(ptr[len]); ptr[len--] = NULL;}
    if (free_seg) free(ptr);
}

freev(ptr, N, TRUE); /* if known length */
freev(ptr, -1, TRUE); /* if NULL-terminated */
freev(ptr, -1, FALSE); /* to keep array */
```

### Patrician

[GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.58/) functions:

- [`g_ptr_array_free()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.58/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strfreev) for freeing arrays of pointers,
- [`g_strfreev()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.58/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strfreev) for freeing arrays of strings.

I find it hard to do any serious C programming without GLib. It introduces things such as [dynamic strings](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.58/glib-Strings.html) and lays [foundations](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.58/glib-Keyed-Data-Lists.html#g-datalist-foreach) for [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). It should really be part of the standard C run-time library. It would give C a breath of fresh air. It would make C a reasonable and competitive language again **for the year 2019.** But because it isn’t, it will add 1 MB to your application (either in DLL size or in executable size). Also the Windows distribution is [maintained by sadists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34584025/gnome-glib-status-for-windows-osx-unix-like-and-binaries).

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=0;i<N;i++) free(ptr[i]);
free(ptr);
```

you are not checking for malloc failure to allocate. You should always check.

Answer (score 1):

```html
void freeMatrix(int **matrix ,int row)
{
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        free(matrix[i]);
    }
    free(matrix);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You may find your answer has more value if you explain the code you have provided.