# Initialising a 2d-array with zeros; printing its values reveals that not every element contains a 0

Tags: c, malloc, multidimensional-array

I already searched for an answer here, but I couldn't find something that suits my case.

I have a function make_array(), which generates a 2-dimensional array, and has to fill it with zeros.
When calling this function in main() and printing the values, there's a strange output, which is non-reproducible on other machines...

```
[...]    
Valuearray[0][13]: 0
Valuearray[0][14]: 65
Valuearray[0][15]: 0
[...]
```

The rest of the array contains Zeros.
Searching for an answer I randomly changed

```
Array[i][j] = 0;
```

to

```
Array[i][j] = 123;
```

and got

```
Valuearray[0][0]: 0
Valuearray[0][1]: 0
Valuearray[0][2]: 0
Valuearray[0][3]: 0
Valuearray[0][4]: 0
Valuearray[0][5]: 0
Valuearray[0][6]: 0
Valuearray[0][7]: 0
Valuearray[0][8]: 0
Valuearray[0][9]: 0
Valuearray[0][10]: 0
Valuearray[0][11]: 0
Valuearray[0][12]: 0
Valuearray[0][13]: 0
Valuearray[0][14]: 65
Valuearray[0][15]: 0
Valuearray[0][16]: 123
[...]
```

the rest contains 123. So just the first 16 Elements don't get changed by the for-loop.

The code of my program:

```
//#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int global_file_count = 10;
const int global_max_x_coord = 309;
const int global_min_x_coord = 111;


int** make_array(int SizeY, int SizeX){ // SizeY=global_file_count+1, 
                                        // SizeX=global_max_x_coord-global_min_x_coord

    //http://pleasemakeanote.blogspot.de/2008/06/2d-arrays-in-c-using-malloc.html

    int** Array;  
    Array = (int**) malloc((SizeX)*sizeof(int*)); 
    for (int i = 0; i < SizeX; i++) {
       Array[i] = (int*) malloc((SizeY)*sizeof(int));
   }

    for (int i=1;i<=SizeY;i++){ // should fill everything element with 0 (????)
        for(int j=0;j<=SizeX;j++){
                Array[i][j] = 123;
        }
    }

return Array;
    free(Array);
}

int main(){

    int** Valuearray = make_array(global_file_count+1, (global_max_x_coord-global_min_x_coord));

    for (int i=0;i<=global_file_count+1;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=(global_max_x_coord-global_min_x_coord);j++){
                printf("Valuearray[%i][%i]: %i\n", i, j, Valuearray[i][j]);
        }
    }
    free(Valuearray);
}
```

Also, when I plant an extra

```
Array[0][14] = 0;
```

before

```
return Array;
```

in my make_array()-function, everything is fine and the value gets changed. But I'd really rather let my for-loop do this...

My **question** is: As it this non-reproducible, what can I do about it? And what is the reason for this?
I am using Ubuntu 12.10., Sublime Text 2 as IDE, and gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2 as Compiler, if this information is useful. 
Thanks in advance and sorry for this big pile of text.

Comment: side note : `free(ValueArray)` isn't sufficient to de-allocate this 2D array. You need to have a `free` corresponding to every `malloc`.

Comment: You are not constructing a 2D array but only an emulation with it through pointers to pointers. There is no need to do this in C. Also don't cast the return of `malloc`, this may hide sutle bugs.

Comment: "As it this non-reproducible" **undefined behavior** rarely *is* consistently reproducible, and there is plenty of it in this code. Check your array indexing (remember, C is 0-based through (N-1) for a N-sized array). Likewise, as Sander pointed out, this leaks everything allocated except the pointer vector, which is ironic in that it is required for accessing all the sub-vectors for `free()`ing. Once it is gone, the others are unreachable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When filling the array, you need to swap around the use of `SizeX` and `SizeY`, since `SizeX` is the range of the first index, and `SizeY` of the second.

Additionally, you need to start indexing at `0`, and end at `size - 1` (for whatever the `size` is).

So :

```
for (int i = 0; i < SizeX; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < SizeY; j++) {
        Array[i][j] = 123;
    }
}
```

(note that you'll also have to fix the indexes in the loop that prints the contents of the array)

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped! Such a simple mistake... All this fiddling around with arrays must have made me lose my focus.

Comment: @pxlbrnd Please see the link I added in my answer about free'ing 2D arrays

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
for (int i=0;i<SizeX;i++){ // should fill everything element with 0 (????)
    for(int j=0;j<SizeY;j++){
            Array[i][j] = 0;
    }
}
```

or replace `malloc()` with `calloc()` instead of the above for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You swapped `SizeX` and `SizeY` when filling in the array, this is correct:

```
for ( i=0;i<SizeX;i++){ // should fill everything element with 0 (????)
    for( j=0;j<SizeY;j++){
```

Additionally, you are indexing one too many times in your loops, for example:

```
for (int i=1;i<=SizeY;i++)
             ^^^^^^^^
```

should be:

```
for (int i=1;i<SizeY;i++)
```

So you are going out of bounds which is undefined behavior. Also, this this [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666214/how-to-free-c-2d-array) on free'ing 2D arrays.