# Gnome glib status for Windows/OSX/Unix-like and binaries

Tags: windows, macos, unix, glib, genome

I am trying to understand which is the current situation of glib regarding Windows, Unix-Like (not necessary Linux) and OSX. I am analyzing if I could use glib for a project and I will need all those OS working.

I am searching the binaries of Windows and the last I found are very old (from 2010 and 2011). Does this mean that windows support is being dropped by Gnome glib?

I need to know if latest glib is still working for all that platforms and if it is at least in planned to continue in the near future.

The second question is what is the easiest path to find binaries for each platform. Should I need to cross compile myself for each platform? Or are there prebuilds somewhere? If there are binaries, please let me know where. As I said, for Windows I found them to be very very old. For OSX is it via brew for example?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

GLib supports win32 rather well they just don't provide binaries. The Gtk website lists some third party distributions of binaries for Windows: http://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php. Also cross-compiling is a solid option too.

OSX is a little more complicated: Homebrew is certainly one option but their builds are not really distribution friendly IME, JHBuild is a PITA to work with but once everything is setup it works well, then there are options like macports which I am not familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

As for windows, the official gtk website from the other answer proposes to use MSYS to get binaries and it does offer some recent versions. But they all depend on MSYS stuff (like msys-gcc_s1.dll, etc) and I didn't want any additional dependencies.

So the best I've found so far were **GLib** binaries from http://win32builder.gnome.org/packages/3.6/ (version 2.34.2 for both win x32 and x64). There is also a newer version of GLib (2.38.2) available only for win x32 here https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/

You will also need GLib some dependencies compiled - **libiconv** and **libintl**. The best I've found for these are:

the same location for libiconv (http://win32builder.gnome.org/packages/3.6/) (version 1.13.1 both bitnesses) or  a slightly newer version (1.14) but only x32 here https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MinGW/Base/libiconv/libiconv-1.14-2/

worse with libintl - an older x32 version (0.14) here https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/libintl/0.14.4/ , or a newer (0.18.1) x32 version from a non-trusted source here https://ru.dll-files.com/libintl-8.dll.html . Even worse for libintl x64 version - I didn't manage to find any except some old version from our closed repo which I have no idea where it came from.

**P.S.** If you're interested in some Linux prebuilt versions, I found plenty using rpmfind.net, namely you can find linux GLib (2.52.1) for x32 here ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/fedora-secondary/development/rawhide/Everything/i386/os/Packages/g/ and for x64 here ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/g/