# Correct primitive array size

Tags: objective-c, primitive-types

I'm trying to use a lighter primitive array, because storing hundreds of thousands NSNumbers in a NSMutableDictionary is causing like 40-50MB memory consumption..

This is my code:

```
NSUInteger highestModelID = [self.externalDB intForQuery:@"SELECT `id` FROM `models` ORDER BY `id` DESC"];

CGFloat modelsPricesForCustomer[highestModelID];
memset(modelsPricesForCustomer, 0, highestModelID*sizeof(NSUInteger));

NSLog(@"%i", highestModelID);
NSLog(@"%lu", (sizeof modelsPricesForCustomer));
```

`highestModelID` is `34078`, yet the size says it's `136312`. Do I allocate it wrong or read it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`highestModelID` is the number of elements in `modelsPricesForCustomer`, not its size. `sizeof`, on the other hand, returns the size of the array in bytes, i.e. `highestModelID*sizeof(CGFloat)`

Since `sizeof(CGFloat)` on your system is 4, the results are correct:

```
34078 * 4 = 136312
```

Note:

```
memset(modelsPricesForCustomer, 0, highestModelID*sizeof(NSUInteger));
//                                                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

should be

```
memset(modelsPricesForCustomer, 0, highestModelID*sizeof(CGFloat));
//                                                       ^^^^^^^
```

to avoid clearing part of memory or going past the end of allocated buffer when `sizeof(NSUInteger) != sizeof(CGFloat)`

Comment: Yes I noticed I wrote the `memset` wrong; it should indeed be `sizeof(CGFloat)`. I also should probably do `(highestModelID + 1) * sizeof(CGFloat)` so I can actually set the final ID in it's range. Thanks for the hint :). I'll accept the answer when the time is over.

Comment: @Allendar Do not use the `+ 1` in the `memset`. If you do you will overwrite memory beyond the array. That's bad.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks for the tip! I changed it back.   Can I actually set `CGFloat modelsPricesForCustomer[highestModelID]` in some way as a `@property` or should use a `static` to solve this? The problem is that the `highestModelID` is only known after running the query. `CGFloat modelsPricesForCustomer[]` obviously won't work.

Comment: @rmaddy how could I make it available class-wide? `static` doesn't seem to work with variable-sized.

Comment: @Allendar You can have the pointer to your array as a property. For example `@property (nonatomic) CGFloat* modelsPricesForCustomer`. If you do this, you'll also have to make your `highestModelID` accessible – so other classes know the array's size.

Comment: What should `self.highestModelUnitPrices[highestModelID];` be like? I can't assign it.

Comment: @Allendar You should be using `self.highestModelUnitPrices = calloc(highestModelID, sizeof(CGFloat))` (this will create your array with elements set to 0). Make sure to `free()` it when done though (probably in dealloc if it lasts for the object's lifetime)

Comment: That works great thank you. One last question; how could I do `calloc` with `CGFloat multiDimArray[int][int]` ?

Comment: You'll want to use a pointer to an array of pointers (`CGFloat**`). You'll need to `malloc()` the array of pointers, with a size of the array width * sizeof the elements. You'll then need to `calloc()` the individual array 'rows' with size of the array height * sizeof the elements. [See here for a slightly better answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970698/using-malloc-for-allocation-of-multi-dimensional-arrays-with-different-row-lengt). You'll also have to repeat the same (reversed) process for [freeing the array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666214/how-to-free-c-2d-array).