# How do I free 2D array allocated with malloc?

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, free, double-pointer

How do I free this array? Is this enough? Would it be enough to write only `free(arr)`? Do I need to free `**arr`? If yes, how can I do that?
Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define N 5
int main(void)
{
    int **arr = malloc(N*sizeof(int*));

    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        arr[i] = malloc(N*sizeof(int));
    }
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        free(arr[i]);
    free(**arr);

    return 0;         
}
```

Comment: You don't need to free the array in this case because the allocations are not repeated and the OS will free the memory after the execution ends. For more information, see [c - What REALLY happens when you don't free after malloc? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654754/what-really-happens-when-you-dont-free-after-malloc)

Comment: If you have to free memory (long-running process that might conceivably starve), then the rule is "Free whatever you malloc".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to free 2d array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666214/how-to-free-2d-array-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to free `**arr` because `**arr` is an `int`.

Instead of that, you should free the allocated pointer `arr`.

The line

```
    free(**arr);
```

should be

```
    free(arr);
```

Comment: thank you so much!! and what about the loop arr[i]? i need to run it or just write free(arr)?

Comment: @danielevanenko The loop is required if you want to manually free everything you allocated. Practically no `free()` here are required because the memory used will be freed by the OS after exiting of the process.

Answer (score 1):

`**arr` in this case is equivalent to `arr[0][0]`, which is actually an integer, and `free` function expects a pointer to memory. So `free(**arr)` would be "freeing" an integer pretending to be a pointer in memory, and that would cause your program to crash.

What you need to do is free a pointer to array of 5 pointers, and this pointer is simply arr. So you need to `free(arr)`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to declare two-dimensional array instead of the array of pointers (and I think that is your idea)

```
int foo(size_t x, size_t y)
{
    int (*arr)[x][y];

    arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr));

    (*arr)[4][2] = 5;

    free(arr);


}
```

You can index it as any other array and you need only one `free`